# How to use Hits Algorithm in JUNG?

Tags: jung

I'm using JUNG library in my project and hits algorithm specificaly.
I have constructed a graph G using Graph Stream, and I Would like to use this same graph G as an input to the JUNG Hits algorithm, but I have a problem in my code.

This this how I created the graph :

```
        SingleGraph graph=FileHelper.createGraph("Graphe", adjacencyMatrixboolean);
        for (org.graphstream.graph.Node node : graph.getNodeSet())
            node.addAttribute("ui.label", node.getId());
        for (Edge edge : graph.getEdgeSet())
            edge.addAttribute("ui.label", edge.getId());
        graph.display();
```

And this is how I called JUNG HITS lgorithm:

```
HITS ranker = new HITS((edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.Graph)graph);
ranker.evaluate();
ranker.printRankings(true,false);
```

Eclipse show me this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.graphstream.graph.implementations.SingleGraph cannot be cast to edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.Graph
>       at com.tweets.test.Main.main(Main.java:71)

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that `SingleGraph`, whatever that is (it's not part of JUNG), does not implement the JUNG `Graph` interface.  Hence the `ClassCastException`.

To get this to work, you will probably need to build a JUNG `Graph` out of the `SingleGraph`--or write code to build a JUNG `Graph` based on your file.

Comment: Can you please give me a link or a document on how to start building a graph? or how to build a graph with jung from an adjacency matrix?

Comment: If you want to build a JUNG graph based on your file, you may want to look at some of the classes in the `io` subpackage, in particular `MatrixFile`.  If you want to build a graph based on an adjacency matrix in memory, basically you want to create an empty `Graph`, iterate through the matrix and call addEdge([edge object possibly based on the matrix entry], row, column) if the entry is non-empty.